# How to delete an outlier from a np.where condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have this dataframe that has an outlier, which I recognized through a boxplot. Then, I caught the value of it through np.where but the thing is, I don't know how to delete this value and its whole row from my dataframe so that I can get rid of the outlier.

This is the code I used for it so far:

```
sns.boxplot(x=df_cor_inc['rt'].astype(float))
outlier = np.where(df_cor_inc['rt'].astype(float)>50000)
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `np.where`, a simple boolean mask will do the trick:

```py
df_cor_inc = df_cor_inc[df_cor_inc['rt'] <= 50000]]
```

Also, why are you casting `df_cor_inc['rt']` as `float`? Is it not already numeric?

If you want to reset the indices of your dataframe, tack on a `.reset_index(drop=True)`.

Comment: thank you! it is already numeric but it's written as a string

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
df_cor_inc[np.where(df_cor_inc['rt'].astype(float)>50000,False,True)]
```